# Border Radius generator stopped working without a reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created an online CSS3 Border Radius generator.Everything was working fine until yesterday when is stopped working.I tried using the Javascript console from Firefox an told me to look at line 83 of my code.I looked it but I can't figure out what's wrong since I am new to Javascript.Can you help me?Thanks in advance!!!
This is line 81 to 83:

$("#generator").css(corner, newRad);/*also change and the outter radius*/

});}

This is my code:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS3 Border Radius generator</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <META NAME="author" CONTENT="kounelios13">
        <META NAME="subject" CONTENT="programming">
        <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="Create rounded corners for whatever object you want with this border radius generator">
        <META NAME="Classification" CONTENT="No javascript is needed just pure CSS3">
        <META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="programming,web design,tools,generator">
        <META NAME="Designer" CONTENT="kounelios13">
        <META NAME="distribution" CONTENT="Global">
        <META NAME="country" CONTENT="Greece">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/general.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/navbar-head.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/apps/borderRadius(old).css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../js/prefixfree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../js/apps/borderRadius.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



</head>
<body>
<?php include '../menu.php'; ?>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron bg-info">

            <h1 class="text-center text-info">CSS3 border radius generator v0.1 BETA</h1>

            <p>The only thing you have to do is to change each slider and get the code.So <span class="text-info">simple</span>
            Or you can enter your own values in the form bellow and see the results. <strong>Results are in px but in the form you can use whatever you want</strong>.
            To reset the shape type 0 in the form and press submit.

            </p>


            </div>
            <div>
            <input type="text" id="userSet" class="btn bg-success text-info text-center formed form-import" placeholder="Enter your own values"/><button  class="btn btn-danger formed" onclick="setForm()">Submit</button>
            </div>



            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="range" class="ranges form-control pull-left" id="tl" min="0" max="1000" step="1" value="0" >   
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="range" class="ranges pull-right form-control" id="tr" min="0" max="1000" step="1" value="0" >  </div></div>
            <div id="codearea" class="pull-right" >
                <!--This is the basic div for transformations-->

            </div>
            <div id="output" class="pull-left bg-info">
                <!--Here starts the code from the sliders-->
                 border-radius:<span class="topl"></span> <span class="topr"></span> <span class="botl"></span> <span class="botr"> </span>
                <div class="prefixed"> -webkit-border-radius:<span class="topl"></span> <span class="topr"></span> <span class="botl"></span> <span class="botr"></span>
                 -moz-border-radius:<span class="topl"></span> <span class="topr"></span> <span class="botl"></span> <span class="botr"></span></div>
                 <!--Here it ends-->
                <div class='formed'>

                 Code from text input:<br>
                 border-radius:<span class="form-output"></span>;</div>
                 <div class="prefixed">
                 -webkit-border-radius:<span class="form-output"></span>;</span><br>
                 -moz-border-radius:<span class="form-output"></span>;</span><br>
                 <a onclick="$('.prefixed').toggle(893);" class="btn btn-danger ">Toggle prefixes</a>
                 <a onclick="$('.formed').toggle(893);" class="btn btn-danger ">Toggle form input</a>
                </div>


            </div>


        </div><br>
        <div class="container upside">
            <div class="row"><div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="range" class="ranges form-control pull-left" id="bl" min="0" max="1000" step="1" value="0">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">  
            <input type="range" class="ranges form-control pull-right" id="br" min="0" max="1000" step="1" value="0" >
            </div></div>    <br>
            <div class="btn btn-info" onclick="$('.navbar-footer').toggle(890);">Toggle footer</div>
        </div>  

        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-bottom navbar-footer navbar-foot">
            <div class="container">
                <p >Site build by <a href="http://kounelios13.blogspot.gr" class="navbar-btn btn btn-primary ">kounelios13</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

My Javascript file:

```
var user=function(){
        $first=$("#tl").val();
        $second=$("#tr").val();
        $third=$("#bl").val();
        $fourth=$("#br").val();

            $(".topl").html($first+"px");
            $(".topr").html($second+"px");
            $(".botl").html($third+"px");
            $(".botr").html($fourth+"px");


        };

function  setForm() {
  $(".ranges").val(0);/*Reset each slider back to 0*/
  $("#output span").html("0px");/*Erases the code generated by the sliders*/

$('#codearea').css('border-radius', $('#userSet').val());
var val=document.getElementById('userSet');
var formCode=val.value;
$('.form-output').html(formCode);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  $radiusTrue=$("#otherWay").val();
  $("#submit").click(


    function(){




      var raded=$("#otherWay").text();
      $codearea.css(raded);





    }




    )
  $('.botr').after(';<br>');
    var $property = $(".code");
    var $codearea =  $("#codearea");


    $('.ranges').on('change',function() {
         if (raded != null){
          $codearea.css("border-radius","0px")
         }
         else{

        var newRad = $(this).val() + "px",
            corner;
        switch($(this).attr('id')) {
             case 'tl' :
                corner = "border-top-left-radius";


                break;
          case 'tr' :
               corner = "border-top-right-radius";

             break;
       case 'bl' :
               corner = "border-bottom-left-radius";

           case 'br' :
               corner = "border-bottom-right-radius";

               break;                
        }
        $codearea.css(corner, newRad);
       user();

        $("#generator").css(corner, newRad);/*also change and the outter radius*/

    });}
});
```

Comment: SO isn't a 'dump my entire code and someone will figure out the problem and fix it for me' site.

Comment: Sorry but I am asking for help me.I am not waiting for someone to correct my code.I am  justwaiting for someone  to help me figure what's wrong.

Comment: it would help if you marked where line 83 is, im pretty sure no one is going to count 83 lines...

Comment: Yeah I am sorry you are right.I am going to fix it right now.

Comment: i believe your issue is in line `});}` this is most likely line 83. see the 2nd `}` is redundant, remove it and check again. should be only `});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this code.It is almost the same but much simplier:

```
   $(document).ready(

    function(){
     $(".ranges").change(function(){
    $tl=$("#tl").val()+"px ";
    $tr=$("#tr").val()+"px ";
    $bl=$("#bl").val()+"px ";
    $br=$("#br").val()+"px ";
    $code=$tl+$tr+$bl+$br;
    $("#generator").css("border-radius",$code);


    });


});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are loading jQuery twice, and two different versions!

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is it bad to load 2 different versions of jquery?

Comment: Yes. It will break you code a majority of the time. The thing to ask is why would you really want two versions! You should remove the oldest one and then work on your code.

Comment: Because I am a stupid seriously neither know I the reason for using 2 versions

Answer (score 0):

you have got some bad closed functions in you javascript. Here you get the working code:

```
var user = function() {
  $first = $("#tl").val();
  $second = $("#tr").val();
  $third = $("#bl").val();
  $fourth = $("#br").val();

  $(".topl").html($first + "px");
  $(".topr").html($second + "px");
  $(".botl").html($third + "px");
  $(".botr").html($fourth + "px");
};

function  setForm() {
  $(".ranges").val(0);/*Reset each slider back to 0*/
  $("#output span").html("0px");/*Erases the code generated by the sliders*/

  $('#codearea').css('border-radius', $('#userSet').val());
  var val = document.getElementById('userSet');
  var formCode = val.value;
  $('.form-output').html(formCode);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $radiusTrue = $("#otherWay").val();
  $("#submit").click(function() {

    var raded = $("#otherWay").text();
    $codearea.css(raded);
  });
  $('.botr').after(';<br>');
  var $property = $(".code");
  var $codearea = $("#codearea");
  $('.ranges').on('change', function() {
    if (raded != null) {
      $codearea.css("border-radius", "0px")
    } else {
      var newRad = $(this).val() + "px",
              corner;
      switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
        case 'tl' :
          corner = "border-top-left-radius";
          break;
        case 'tr' :
          corner = "border-top-right-radius";
          break;
        case 'bl' :
          corner = "border-bottom-left-radius";
        case 'br' :
          corner = "border-bottom-right-radius";
          break;
      }
      $codearea.css(corner, newRad);
      user();
      $("#generator").css(corner, newRad); /*also change and the outter radius*/
    }
  });
});
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i fixed the problems I had by removing 
an if else condition  but the values that appear in my coe output are not the same with the actual values :

```
var user=function(){
        $first=$("#tl").val();
        $second=$("#tr").val();
        $third=$("#bl").val();
        $fourth=$("#br").val();

            $(".topl").html($first+"px");
            $(".topr").html($second+"px");
            $(".botl").html($third+"px");
            $(".botr").html($fourth+"px");


        };

function  setForm() {
  $(".ranges").val(0);/*Reset each slider back to 0*/
  $("#output span").html("0px");/*Erases the code generated by the sliders*/

$('#codearea').css('border-radius', $('#userSet').val());
var val=document.getElementById('userSet');
var formCode=val.value;
$('.form-output').html(formCode);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  $radiusTrue=$("#otherWay").val();
  $("#submit").click(


    function(){




      var raded=$("#otherWay").text();
      $codearea.css(raded);





    }




    )
  $('.botr').after(';<br>');
    var $property = $(".code");
    var $codearea =  $("#codearea");


    $('.ranges').on('change',function() {

          $codearea.css("border-radius","0px")


        var newRad = $(this).val() + "px",
            corner;
        switch($(this).attr('id')) {
             case 'tl' :
                corner = "border-top-left-radius";


                break;
          case 'tr' :
               corner = "border-top-right-radius";

             break;
       case 'bl' :
               corner = "border-bottom-left-radius";

           case 'br' :
               corner = "border-bottom-right-radius";

               break;                
        }
        $codearea.css(corner, newRad);
       user();

        $("#generator").css(corner, newRad);/*also change and the outter radius*/

    });
});
```